# Solving a Forced Oscillations Differential Equation Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

*A building consists of two floors. The first floor is attached rigidly to the ground, and the second floor is of mass m = 1000 slugs (fps units) and weighs 16 tons (32,000 lb). The elastic frame of the building behaves as a spring that resists horizontal displacements of the second floor; it requires a horizontal force of 5 tons to displace the second floor a distance of 1 ft. Assume that in an earthquake the ground oscillates horizontally with amplitude A0 and circular frequency ω, resulting in an external horizontal force*

$F(t) = m A_0 \omega^2 \sin(\omega t)$

*on the second floor.*

*a) What is the natural frequency (in hertz) of oscillations of the second floor?*

*b) If the ground undergoes one oscillation every 2.25s with an amplitude of 3 in, what
is the amplitude of the resulting forced oscillations of the second floor?*

Above is the full textbook question. I'm having difficulty fully understanding what the second part of the problem entails. Here's what I've done so far:

$m = 1000 [slugs]$

$F_g = 32000 [lbs]$

$F_k = kx$

$F(t) = mA_0\omega^2\sin(\omega t)$

$\omega_0 = \sqrt(k/m) = \sqrt(10000/1000) = \sqrt10$; answers part a

$mx'' + kx = F(t), c = 0$

$F_0 = A_0\omega^2$

$\omega = 1 (cycle)/(2.25 [s])$

$A_0 = 3 [in]$

Comment: which book is this?

Comment: Elementary Differential Equations with Boundary Value Problems, 6th Edition ;; C. Henry Edwards & David E. Penney

Comment: so in your case  what is unknown?  as i understand  you have found  amplitude ,angular frequency  right?what is actual problem?

Comment: Part b. I'm not quite sure what it's asking me. The answer should be ~10.625 [in.] but I don't even know how to arrive there.

Comment: so you should use  $F_0=A_0*W^2$  this formula right?i can  type angular frequency  sorry